# Add Method Wizard in VS 2010 Express

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How do I create Add Method Wizard in VS C# 2010 Express. It was something like right click on a class library and Add method in Visual Studio.Net 2003. Now when I right click on the class I don't see Add method menu.
any Help please? Thanks

Comment: You could just type it. `void Foo() { }`.

Comment: it can be typed but that was something more of a class designer. May be express edition missing this feature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'wizard' like ways to add a method are

- through the class diagram, not in Express
- use it first (in another method) and select "generate method stub"
- by using a snippet, you'll have to create one first